# Why does my Activity always show the same set of data from a GCM notification?

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

I have implemented a simple GCM client and I am having this problem when updating the Activity which launches each time a new notification is received. Every time I send a notification with a set of parameters, only the parameters I sent for the first notification appears in the UI. When I try changing the parameters, they don't show up (the same data is shown again).

Here is my GcmIntentService class

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

private static final String TAG = "GcmIntentService";

public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                .equals(messageType)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "GCM error -> MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR");
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString(), "", "",
                    "", "");
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                .equals(messageType)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "GCM error -> MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED");
            sendNotification(
                    "Deleted Messages on server: " + extras.toString(), "",
                    "", "", "");
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                .equals(messageType)) {
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "GCM success. Received data: fromUser="
                            + extras.getString("fromUser") + " message="
                            + extras.getString("message") + " srcLat="
                            + extras.getString("srcLat") +" srcLng="
                            + extras.getString("srcLng") + " dstLat="
                            + extras.getString("dstLat") + " dstLng="
                            + extras.getString("dstLng"));
            sendNotification(
                    extras.getString("fromUser") + " "
                            + extras.getString("message"),
                            extras.getString("srcLat"), extras.getString("srcLng"),
                            extras.getString("dstLat"), extras.getString("dstLng"));
        }

    }

    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

}

private void sendNotification(String msg, String srcLat, String srcLng,
        String dstLat, String dstLng) {

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowUser.class);
    intent.putExtra("message", msg);
    intent.putExtra("srcLat", srcLat);
    intent.putExtra("srcLng", srcLng);
    intent.putExtra("dstLat", dstLat);
    intent.putExtra("dstLng", dstLng);

    Log.d(TAG, "-> sendNotification -> Received parameters:\nmessage:"
            + msg + "\nsrcLat=" + srcLat + "\nsrcLng=" + srcLng
            + "\ndstLat=" + dstLat + "\ndstLng=" + dstLng);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("New Taxi Request Received")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

}

}
```

And here is my Activity which launches on click of the notification.

```
public class ShowUser extends Activity {

private TextView messageTextView;
private TextView showUsernameTextView;
private TextView srcLatTextView;
private TextView srcLngTextView;
private TextView dstLatTextView;
private TextView dstLngTextView;

private SharedPreferences prefs;

private String username;

private static final String TAG = "ShowUser";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_user_details);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    String srcLat = intent.getStringExtra("srcLat");
    String srcLng = intent.getStringExtra("srcLng");
    String dstLat = intent.getStringExtra("dstLat");
    String dstLng = intent.getStringExtra("dstLng");

    Log.d(TAG, "ReceivedExtras: message=" + message
            + "srcLat=" + srcLat + "srcLng=" + srcLng
            + "dstLat=" + dstLat + "dstLng=" + dstLng);

    prefs = getSharedPreferences(DriverLoginActivity.USER_CREDENTIALS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    username = prefs.getString(DriverLoginActivity.USERNAME, null);

    if(username!= null) {
        messageTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        showUsernameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showUsernameTextView);
        srcLatTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sourceLatTextView);
        srcLngTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sourceLngTextView);
        dstLatTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.destinationLatTextView);
        dstLngTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.destinationLngTextView);

        showUsernameTextView.setText("Welcome " + username);
        messageTextView.setText(message);
        srcLatTextView.setText("Source Latitude: " + srcLat);
        srcLngTextView.setText("Source Longitude: " + srcLng);
        dstLatTextView.setText("Destination Latitude: " + dstLat);
        dstLngTextView.setText("Destination Longitude: " + dstLng);

    }

}

}
```

I think it probably has got something to do with the `PendingIntent` but I'm not sure what is going on here since I'm relatively new to using `PendingIntent`s and notifications in Android. Can anyone please tell me what is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `sendNotification` you get the `PendingIntent` using this code:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        intent, 0);
```

The first time you do this, Android will create a new `PendingIntent` using the `Intent` that you provide as the 3rd parameter of this call. The following times you do this, Android will not create a new `PendingIntent`, but will return a token that refers to the first `PendingIntent` that you created.

If you want Android to replace the "extras" on the original `PendingIntent` when you execure this code the next time, you need to use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` as the 4th parameter in the call to `getActivity()`. This will still return a token that referes to the first `PendingIntent` that you created, but it will also replace all the "extras" in that original `PendingIntent` with the "extras" present in the `Intent` passed as the 3rd parameter.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. @DavidWasser please do you think you could give me your opinion on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598696/recommended-way-order-to-read-data-from-a-webservice-parse-that-data-and-inse